# Angular2 menu multilevel dropdown doesn't work

Tags: jquery, angular, dropdown

I have this problem, the level two not appear in the dropdown

```
index. html
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>angular2 playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app')
          .catch(console.error.bind(console));
      $(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
            var current=$(this).next();
            var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
            if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
                $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
            current.toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
            var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
            root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
        });
    });
      </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>

  </my-app>

  </body>



</html>

---------------------------------------------------------------------
app.ts

    //our root app component
    import {Component} from '@angular/core'

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      providers: [],
      template: `
       <div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Here <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 1 the other level dont enter</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 2</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 3</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      `,
      directives: []
    })
    export class App {
      constructor() {
        this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
      }
    }
```

---

main.ts

```
//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App, [])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

---

https://plnkr.co/edit/9LVuek8bQ7mNgoqaC5Y6?p=preview

the dropdown work fine, but if I add the code to a component of angular in a template when the html is rendering and you navigate for the dropdown don't show the level 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several way to do that:

1) Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger", function(e){
```

See plunker example here https://plnkr.co/edit/O6pfV7mrLWiGZ2KHwqh8?p=preview

2) Init event handlers after angular2 view has been rendered

```
export class App {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.initMenu();
  }
  initMenu() {
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
            var current=$(this).next();
    ...
```

See plunker example here https://plnkr.co/edit/2DRVOGhcIMkTgQHTM57d?p=preview

3) Use angular2 approach instead jQuery manipulation:

**root component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {MenuItem} from './menu-item.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Here <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="menu-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of menu" [data]="menuItem"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  `,
  directives: [MenuItem]
})
export class App {
  menu = [
    {
      title: 'Level 1 the other level dont enter'
      items: [
         {
            title: 'Level 2'
         },
         {
            title: 'Level 2',
            items: [
               {
                  title: 'Level 3'
               },
               {
                  title: 'Level 3'
               },
               {
                  title: 'Level 3',
                  items: [
                     {
                        title: 'Level 4'
                     },
                     {
                        title: 'Level 4'
                     },
                     {
                        title: 'Level 4'
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            title: 'Level 2'
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Level 1'
    },
        {
      title: 'Level 1'
    }
  ];
}
```

**menu-item component**

```
import {Component, Input, forwardRef, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core'

interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  items: Array<MenuItem>
}

@Component({
  selector: 'li.menu-item',
  styles: [`
    .block {
      display: block;
    }
  `],
  template: `
   <a [ngClass]="{'right-caret': !!data.items && !opened, 'left-caret': !!data.items && opened}" (click)="onClick($event)">{{data.title}}</a>
   <template [ngIf]="!!data.items">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" [ngClass]="{'block': opened}">
     <li class="menu-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of data.items" [data]="menuItem">
     </li>
    </ul>
   </template>
  `,
  directives: [forwardRef(()=> MenuItem)]
})
export class MenuItem {
  @Input() data: MenuItem;
  @ViewChildren(MenuItem) children:QueryList<MenuItem>;
  private _opened: boolean = false;
  get opened() {
    return this._opened;
  };
  set opened(val) {
    this._opened = val;
    if(!val) {
      this.children.toArray().forEach(x => x.opened = false)
    }
  }
  onClick(e){
    this.opened = !this.opened;
    if(this.data.items) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the link to working example [plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/zG0Q5Q3dsmJqsplZKG7e?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @yorzui, well I know that I need learn more angular2, excelente code.

Comment: @yurzui; @Marcos José Pérez Pérez: I am just starting out with Angular 2. I was trying out the code  on plunker @ https://plnkr.co/edit/zG0Q5Q3dsmJqsplZKG7e?p=preview. And it doesnt seems to be working. I get two errors: 1.) angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: XHR error (404) loading https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js(…) [ This is in plunker. I fixed it in my code.] 2.) browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError (I think the hash in a href is the issue). Also the click event doesnot get registered.

Comment: @yurzui! Thanks.. but I still get the error "EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError" when I click the dropdown. It seems fine in your plunker. I am not sure why I get it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just plug in smartmenu(http://www.smartmenus.org), very simply, after everything finished

```
   ngAfterViewChecked() {
        $('#main-menu').smartmenus();
   }
```

It is mobile/tablet/ipad friendly and cope with most browser

http://plnkr.co/edit/wLqLUoBQYgcDwOgSoRfF?p=preview

Check my code here: https://github.com/Longfld/DynamicaLoadMultiLevelDropDownMenu